Is this a gcc bug? Function returns 0 when looping an int* over elements of a __m256i
When compiled with gcc the function sum_of_squares returns 0. Am I doing anything wrong or is this a gcc bug? I know that I am not handling cases when n is not divisible by 8.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int sum_of_squares(int x[], int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    __m256i sum8 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 8) {
        __m256i x8 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&x[i]);
        x8 = _mm256_mul_epi32(x8, x8);
        sum8 = _mm256_add_epi32(x8, sum8);
    }

    int *_sum = (int *)&sum8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) sum += _sum[i];
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    _Alignas(32) int x[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
    }
    printf("%d", sum_of_squares(x, 16));
}


I am not that familiar with intrinsics, but usually these things are not bugs. You most likely have Undefined Behavior.  Looking at the assembly gcc compiles sum_of_squares to just xor eax eax ; ret which is a strong indication it proved that any execute path on this function has UB. There is also a "warning: 'sum8' is used uninitialized ".

(__m256i *)&x[i] this looks like out of bounds access. Again, not that familiar with intrinsics

I have checked the asm, no idea why it is compiling to xor %eax, %eax

@bolov: Not accessing outside the object (like you would if you did sum8[i] which GNU C supports, but it defines __m256i as a vector of 4x 64-bit integers so the max idx is 3).  Instead it's strict-aliasing UB.

Strict aliasing violation, undefined behavior here: int *_sum = (int *)&sum8; ... _sum[i]

Especially with integer arithmetic (which, in contrast to FP math, usually is associative), you can very often get away with a trivial loop and let the compiler do the SIMD optimization (compile with -O3, but check the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/G33bos61b

Pointing an int* at __m256i (a GNU C vector of long long elements) violates the strict-aliasing rule.  GCC14.2 -O2 optimizes your function to return 0; because of this.  (xor eax,eax / ret).
We can verify this was the problem by using -fno-strict-aliasing and seeing non-zero results. (See both on Godbolt).
MSVC always allows all aliasing, and it doesn't always break on GCC or Clang, so some people get the wrong idea that code like yours is safe.  It isn't, as this example demonstrates.
Unfortunately -fsanitize=undefined doesn't catch this error (or uninitialized last elem of x[]).
But in general, when you check the asm and see your function optimized away to return 0;, that often means you either returned the wrong variable or there was compile-time-visible UB.  (Sometimes compilers don't even set the return value, or even omit the ret instruction so execution falls into whatever comes next.)
Use _mm256_storeu_si256 to int tmparr[8];  (Or align the tmp array and use _mm256_store_si256).
Or better, see Fastest method to calculate sum of all packed 32-bit integers using AVX512 or AVX2 (and in general Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)) - shuffle the low half down to line up with the low half and do vertical SIMD adds, reducing the number of elements in half each step until you're down to one.  (GCC actually optimizes your reduction loop to a series of shuffles and adds, if you avoid UB.)

Other unrelated bugs in your test case
As Soonts mentioned, you also want vpmulld (_mm256_mullo_epi32) non-widening 32-bit multiply rather than vpmuldq (_mm256_mul_epi32) widening signed multiply that only reads the even elements as produces a 64-bit result.  Your strict-aliasing bug is why you get zero; fixing this is also necessary to get the non-zero result you want, instead of just sums of even elements (0,2, etc.).
You should also init the 16th element (x[15]) which as Soonts points out your current code doesn't do.

__attribute__((may_alias)) lets you typedef a version of int you can point at anything
If you really wanted, you could use typedef int32_t aliasing_i32 __attribute__((may_alias)), which you can safely point at anything that's aligned by 4 or more, using that instead of int for your pointer type.  (Or unaligned if you use __attribute__((may_alias, aligned(1)))).
Fun fact: GCC and Clang's definitions of __m256i use may_alias, allowing you to point __m256i* at anything, but not vice versa.
But there's no advantage to this; the array doesn't take "extra" storage; the __m256i vector optimizes into just a YMM register.  And the reduction loop optimizes into shuffles anyway, but if it didn't, either way of writing this would have 32 bytes of stack space that gets written with vmovdqa and read by a scalar loop.


x8 = _mm256_mul_epi32(x8, x8);

Than instruction doesn’t do what you expect it does. It only uses lowest 32 bits from each 64-bit lane, and computes 4 products, 64 bits each.
To compute 8 32-bits products, consider _mm256_mullo_epi32 instead.

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)

Note you only initializing 15 numbers, then loading 16.

int *_sum = (int *)&sum8;

That works, but typically compiles into a slow code, vector store then scalar loads.
To compute horizontal sum of all numbers in the vector, see that answer.

Thanks for the answer. But why is it returning 0?

@SaiCharanMarrivada It’s possible the compiler detected that you’re using uninitialized value, and “optimized” into zero

@SaiCharanMarrivada: int *_sum = (int *)&sum8; does not work; this answer is wrong.  It's strict-aliasing UB to point an int* at a GNU C vector of long long elements, and code like this does break in practice under GCC with optimization enabled.  See print a __m128i variable re: the UB, and Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction) re: doing it efficiently.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
int sum_of_squares(int x[], int n)
{
        if( 0 != (n+1)%8 )
        {
                // Here n needs to be multiples of 8 - 1
                printf( "sum_of_squares data size parameter needs to be multiples of 8-1\n");
                printf( "data size n: %d n-1: %d\n", n, n-1);
                printf( "Allowed values for n: 7, 15, 23, ...\n");
                return -1;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        __m256i sum8 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 8)
        {
                __m256i initVal = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&x[i]);
                __m256i x8 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&x[i]);
                // x8 = _mm256_mul_epi32(x8, x8);
                x8 = _mm256_mullo_epi32( initVal, x8);
                sum8 = _mm256_add_epi32(x8, sum8);
        }
        int *_sum = (int *)&sum8;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) sum += _sum[i];
        return sum;
}
int main()
{
        {
                _Alignas(32) int x[8];
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                        x[i] = i;
                }
                printf( "sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..7^2 elements: %d\n", sum_of_squares(x, 8-1));
                int n = 8-1;
                printf( "%d*(%d+1)*(2*%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*(%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*%d/6 = %d\n", n, n, n, n, n+1, 2*n, n, n+1, 2*n+1, n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 );
        }
        {
                _Alignas(32) int x[16];
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
                        x[i] = i;
                }
                printf( "sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..15^2 elements: %d\n", sum_of_squares(x, 16-1));
                int n = 16-1;
                printf( "%d*(%d+1)*(2*%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*(%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*%d/6 = %d\n", n, n, n, n, n+1, 2*n, n, n+1, 2*n+1, n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 );
        }
        {
                _Alignas(32) int x[24];
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                {
                        x[i] = i;
                }
                printf( "sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: %d\n", sum_of_squares(x, 24-1));
                int n = 24-1;
                printf( "%d*(%d+1)*(2*%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*(%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*%d/6 = %d\n", n, n, n, n, n+1, 2*n, n, n+1, 2*n+1, n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 );
        }
        {
                _Alignas(32) int x[4];
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                        x[i] = i;
                }
                printf( "sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: %d\n", sum_of_squares(x, 4-1));
                int n = 4-1;
                printf( "%d*(%d+1)*(2*%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*(%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*%d/6 = %d\n", n, n, n, n, n+1, 2*n, n, n+1, 2*n+1, n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 );
        }
        {
                _Alignas(32) int x[13];
                for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
                {
                        x[i] = i;
                }
                printf( "sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: %d\n", sum_of_squares(x, 13-1));
                int n = 13-1;
                printf( "%d*(%d+1)*(2*%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*(%d+1)/6 = %d*%d*%d/6 = %d\n", n, n, n, n, n+1, 2*n, n, n+1, 2*n+1, n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 );
        }
        // I feel better to use mathematical formula instead of wasting memories at RAM and process handlers.
        return 0;
}
/*
$ /usr/bin/gcc.exe -mavx2 -g -Wall sum_of_squares.c -o ./a.out
$ ./a.out
sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..7^2 elements: 140
7*(7+1)*(2*7+1)/6 = 7*8*(14+1)/6 = 7*8*15/6 = 140
sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..15^2 elements: 1240
15*(15+1)*(2*15+1)/6 = 15*16*(30+1)/6 = 15*16*31/6 = 1240
sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: 4324
23*(23+1)*(2*23+1)/6 = 23*24*(46+1)/6 = 23*24*47/6 = 4324
sum_of_squares data size parameter needs to be multiples of 8-1
data size n: 3 n-1: 2
Allowed values for n: 7, 15, 23, ...
sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: -1
3*(3+1)*(2*3+1)/6 = 3*4*(6+1)/6 = 3*4*7/6 = 14
sum_of_squares data size parameter needs to be multiples of 8-1
data size n: 12 n-1: 11
Allowed values for n: 7, 15, 23, ...
sum_of_squares of 0^2+1^2+2^2+..23^2 elements: -1
12*(12+1)*(2*12+1)/6 = 12*13*(24+1)/6 = 12*13*25/6 = 650
*/


Simply rewriting the code isn't as helpful as explaining what was wrong.

@NateEldredge: It doesn't even fix the strict-aliasing UB that resulted in the OP's code producing 0, so will output 0 if compiled with the same optimization options the OP used.  I posted an answer.

Read the comments mentioned inside the program.

I did.  You only fixed the off-by-one error by having the function take the max-index instead of the length, and vpmulld vs. vpmuldq.  You didn't fix the bug making it print 0: strict-aliasing UB from int *_sum = (int *)&sum8;.

If I use gcc -O2 -march=native, your program prints 0 for some, -1 for others.  You compile with the default -O0 so the buggy code happens to work the way the OP wanted.
